# Android Ksoap2 : The method setName(String) is undefined for the type PropertyInfo

Tags: android, ksoap2

In my android program to send a service call to web server I'm getting following error. Please help me...

The method setName(String) is undefined for the type PropertyInfo

```
PropertyInfo sayHelloPI = new PropertyInfo();
    // Set Name
    sayHelloPI.setName("name");
    // Set Value
```

Comment: yes. I've tried. There is no setName() but .name=String is there. Thanx. But I'm still trying to run my project.

Comment: thank u. I'm a beginner in android programming. Let me think and search myself. Will do post if I can not...

Comment: that is a good idea. you search on stackoverflow i am sure some of the posts will help you. if you don't find answers. post a new question with relevant details of what you have tried and what is expected. if your app crashes you post your stacktrace/logcat. Good luck. happy coding!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below

```
    PropertyInfo sayHelloPI = new PropertyInfo();
    sayHelloPI.name="name";
```

http://ksoap2.sourceforge.net/doc/api/org/ksoap2/serialization/PropertyInfo.html

No method as `setName` for `PropertyInfo`

Comment: I am having the same issue.  To add some details on the issue: follow the tutorial [link](http://thiranjith.com/2012/10/15/introduction-to-working-with-ksoap2-in-android/)
When you get to the part where a new instance of PropertyInfo() is created, you will find that the properties in the tutorial does not exist.  The problem is what to use to set the value for PropertyInfo?  PI.value does not exist?